# A basis for the vector space $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have $ V = \mathbb{R}^n$, and have a set $C= \{u_1,...,u_n\}$ whose vectors are linearly independent from each other, do I have a basis that spans the entire $V$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a general theorem of linear algebra that says that if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space and $\{ u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n \}$ is a set of $n$ vectors in $V$, then the following are equivalent:

- $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n$ are linearly independent;
- $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n$ span $V$;
- $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n$ form a basis of $V$.

So the answer to your question is: yes, the vectors in your set $C$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I believe this is the very notion of the basis of a vector space $V$ which is $n$-dimensional: the basis set for $V$ will be a set of $n$ vectors $\{\vec {u_1}, ..., \vec{u_n} \}$ which are linearly independent. Then any element $v \in V$ can be represented as a linear combination of those vectors, i.e. for scalars $c_1, ..., c_n$,

$$v = c_1u_1 + c_2u_2 + ... + c_nu_n$$

As an example, for $\mathbb{R}^2$: the vectors $[1 \; 0]^T$ and $[0 \; 1]^T$ are visibly independent and thus form a well-known basis for the space (in particular, an orthonormal basis).

Comment: Thank you for the help!:)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the vector space generated by these $n$ linearly independent vectors is not $\Bbb R^n$, call it $U$. Then $\dim U=n$, by definition of dimension, and $U\subset \Bbb R^n$ because it is a vector space composed of vectors of $\Bbb R^n$.

Then suppose that $U\neq\Bbb R^n$, this imply that $U\subsetneq \Bbb R^n$, so there is some $v\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $v\notin U$, so $v$ is linearly independent of the basis of $U$ (otherwise it will belong to $U$), what would imply that $\dim\Bbb R^n>n$. But this cannot be possible if you knows that $\dim\Bbb R^n=n$. Hence $U=\Bbb R^n$.